# Can str.translate be used for substring replacement?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How can I use the maketrans() and tranlate() method on a string to get the translated string in Python3?
eg.

In variable

```
s='The quick brown fox'
```

If I have to replace 'The' with '123' in variable 's' how can I do it with these two methods in Python3?

```
output: '123 quick brown fox'
```

Comment: `s.translate(str.maketrans('The', '123'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.translate` is not the right function to use for this particular use case. What it does is, it replaces individual characters by another character. It does not work with character groups. For example:

```
>>> string = 'The quick brown fox and a hound'
>>> tab = str.maketrans('The', '123')
>>> string.translate(tab)
'123 quick brown fox and a 2ound'
```

In addition to translating `'The'`, it also translated the `'h'` in `'hound'`.

For your particular use case, `str.replace` would be a good alternative:

```
>>> string.replace('The', '123')
'123 quick brown fox and a hound'
```